# GAE python ndb - How to get_by_id with projection?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'd like to do this.

```
Content.get_by_id(content_id, projection=['title'])
```

However, I got an error.

```
TypeError: Unknown configuration option ('projection')
```

I should do like this. How?

```
Content.query(key=Key('Content', content_id)).get(projection=['title'])
```

Why bother projection for getting an entity? Because `Content.body` could be large so that I want to reduce db read time and instance hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that following code.

```
Content.query(Content.key == ndb.Key('Content', content_id)).get(projection=['etag'])
```

I found a hint from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

> Don't name a property "key." This name is reserved for a special
>   property used to store the Model key. Though it may work locally, a
>   property named "key" will prevent deployment to App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ndb, the below query should work

```
Content.query(key=Key('Content', content_id)).get(projection=[Content.title])
```

Note: It gets this data from the query index. So, make sure that index is enabled for the column. Reference https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection

Comment: It doesn't work. I got `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler method than the currently posted answers.

As previous answers have mentioned, projections are only for ndb.Queries.

Previous answers suggest to use the entity returned by `get_by_id` to perform a projection query in the form of:

```
<Model>.query(<Model>.key == ndb.Key('<Model>', model_id).get(projection=['property_1', 'property_2', ...])
```

However, you can just manipulate the model's `_properties` directly. (See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass#intro_properties)

For example:

```
desired_properties = ['title', 'tags']

content = Content.get_by_id(content_id)
content._properties = {k: v for k, v in content._properties.iteritems()
                       if k in desired_properties}
print content
```

This would update the entity properties and only return those properties whose keys are in the `desired_properties` list.

Not sure if this is the intended functionality behind `_properties` but it works, and it also prevents the need of generating/maintaining additional indexes for the projection queries.

The only down-side is that this retrieves the entire entity in-memory first. If the entity has arbitrarily large metadata properties that will affect performance, it would be a better idea to use the projection query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Projection is only for query, not get by id. You can put the content.body in a different db model and store only the ndb.Key of it in the Content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll remember as an option.